# Optimizing performance whilst looping over array icw switch

Tags: php, arrays, performance

I am developing an API which will take approximately 100 parameters as possible input. The number of API calls will (hopefully) go into thousands of calls per second and therefore performance is key.

The parameters come in over HTTP GET and POST so I have everything in $_REQUEST. My default code would be something like:

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key=>$value) {
switch ($key) {
    case 'par1':
         // do stuff
         break;
    case 'par2':
         // do stuff
         break;
    case 'par3':
         // etc
```

Now if my $_REQUEST array would contain 10 parameters, the switch statement would run in its entirety 10 times. But that doesn't make any sense to me.

In the old Basic GOTO days it would be possible to use the NEXT key in the array to basically go to the routine that processes that key's contents. All you would need is an additional array with the number of the line to jump to. If I would then sort the array alphabetically by the key, then I would only have to check each parameter a MAXIMUM of one times!

So my question - could I do something similar in PHP so that my code would become:

```
ksort($$_REQUEST);
$keys = array_keys($_REQUEST);
$i = 0;

// now I would preferably like to JUMP to the code where $key is a certain parameter, but my best effort would become:
if ($key[$i] == $par1) {
     // do something with $_REQUEST[$key[$i]]
     $i++;
}
if ($key[$i] == $par2) {
     // again do something with $_REQUEST[$key[$i]]
     $i++;
}
// etc etc
```

But then in the above example I would like to avoid unnecessary checking of parameters somehow.

UPDATE: So ideally I would like something like this, which means calling a function via a pointer or reference:

```
function par1 ($value) {
    // do something
}

function par2 ($value) {
    // do something else
}

foreach ($_REQUEST as $key=>$value)
   call_user_func($key, $value);
```

Would this be faster and save me the average of 50 ifs/cases?

Comment: You can use `continue;` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: Also you will want to use the logical operator `==` and not the assignment operator in an IF statement.

Comment: @Twisty Thanks for the = remark, I corrected that. Continue however skips the rest of the evaluation, which is not what I need - I would actually like to start evaluating the rest of the possible switch values with the NEXT array key (as I did in the second example). But mostly I would like to directly go to the correct comparison.

Comment: Logically - for each key you need to check all the possibilities. Which makes it necessary to have a loop and condition/s (unless you have a limited amount of possible keys). Yes?

Comment: Can you provide some example data that you would expect in $_REQUEST ?

Comment: @OfirBaruch well with the current tools yes - but in Basic you would just do a JSR (jump subroutine) based on the key of the array. Or you could set a fixed amount of lines to jump over and use a GOTO. That saves 100/2 case statements....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve values from a php array using each(), pop() and shift(). An alternative to the switch or chained if statements would be to use an associative array of callbacks. And by using each() with a sorted array, you have an option of progressing through the array without using a loop construct.

But as to the question of which is fastest...it is likely that the overhead of the control structure will be very small relative to the 'something' you are doing to the data. But even if that is the case, the only way to find out which is fastest is to try it out and measure it.

But given the structure of the code you have shown us, one potential avenue for hitting a fast response would be to shard the processing across multiple threads. But this does need a lot of thought - [there are cases where spawning multiple tasks via http requests](http://lampe2e.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/making-stuff-faster-with-curlmultiexec.html) gives good results - but the http and TCP overheads are significant, hence you will usually only see a benefit where the the 'something' is not locally resource intensive but is time consuming. A more efficient solution would be to run a forking daemon or a pool of daemon processes (pool management can be complex) or thread based daemon, communicating with your front end script using shared memory or Unix (filesystem) sockets.

Comment: thanks - I think this may be an additional step later on, but what I'm looking for now is to call functions by pointer or something similar. That would help me to reduce the amount of if/case statements dramatically.

Comment: PS - sorry, I realize you also talk about callbacks. call_user_func() allows this in PHP I just found out (thanks to you). Is that what you mind and is how I added it to the original post what you meant?

Comment: You don't *have* to use `call_user_func($fn[$key], $args);` you can simply `$fn[$key]($arg1, $arg2...);` but do beware that PHP is very differently structured than BASIC and may optimizations are not tansferable between the languages.

Comment: does that mean I can put the function call in $fn[$key] somehow? How do I declare that?

Comment: $fn=array('par1'=>'name_of_your_function', 'par2'=>array($yourObject, 'methodInYourObject'),...); see dox for callbacks...http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php